# Rails, request to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I have three models `Client`, `Service`, `Favourite`. Structure of `Favourite` is:

```
class Favourite
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  #Associations
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Which means `Clients` and `Services` has many `Favourites`. I am creating dashboard for my models. In view where single `Clients` info is shown, I want to show its `Favourites`, same will be on view of single `Services`.

I want to add form to create `Favourites`, but this model will not have its own views. It will be shown through `Clients` and `Services`.

My first idea is to create two different methods for controllers of `Clients` and `Services`.

My second idea is to create separate controller for `Favourites` that will  create this model then redirect to clients and services.

Is it possible to call controller that is not connected with view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a controller without views.

Several options exist:

- Use [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to generate the related data within the parent forms.   No controller is necessary for the favorites.
- Use a form in the parent views that send to a favorites controller,  which redirects back to the parent view.  It just redirects somewhere else with `redirect_to`

  - to use the same controller method but redirect to different parent pages, include a hidden form element `return_to` which can be used to determine where to redirect.  Filter the value though to be sure it's an allowed url, otherwise you might have a security hole.
- Similar to the last option, but use javascript/ajax to send and receive the data.  Again the controller may not have a view, but sends JSON or XML or whatever.

Comment: How I can make my form inside `Clients` view to send data to `Favourites` controller?

Comment: it would require a new form element for the favorite object

Comment: Please privide simple example in you answer message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use polymorphic associations. In `Favourite` you should store `favouritable_id` and `favouritable_type`. `{ favouritable_id: "a", favouritable_type: "Client" }` will mean that `Favourite` is connected with client id "a". To `FavouriteController#create` you need to pass params `id` and `type` of client/service`. In view`render collection: client.favourites`or`render collection: service.favourites`. I am not sure if`Mongoid`classes implement`to_partial_path` method, you can do it yourself it is easy.

Comment: But I want to make it belong to both `Client` and `Service` simultaneously